# LFSR, polynomial , finite field

Tags: finite-field, lfsr

I'm having a hard time understanding the concept of LFSR, polynomials and finite field and how to solve exercises like picture below. Could anyone give me some pointer on where to start?

> [image]

Answer (score 1):

1. translate 'HELLO' to bits.
2. translate 'KIHJF' to bits
3. xor and get the first 25 key bits.
4. the key is the 8 bits initial filling of the register (I'm assuming, but this is common).
5. we have 25 key bits so 25 linear equations in the initial filling. Or if the system has no initial stepping, the first 8 bits are just the initial filling in reversed order. In any case, you can compute the key. [**ADDED:**] no initial stepping (So straight initial filling computation) is indeed the case, as I verified.
6. Now compute the remainder of the key bits and xor them with the remaining ciphertext, to get plain bits and then plain characters.
7. You can compute the characteristic polynomial from 25 bits again: recall the Berlekamp-Massey algorithm.

Comment: 1. translate 'HELLO ' to bits. = 00111 00100 01011 01011 011101.           
2. translate 'KIHJFR' to bits  = 01010 01000 0011 01001 00101                  
3. xor and get the first 30 key bits = 11010 11000 11000 00100 1011 the bits corrosponds to following characters "space" "y" "y" and the last one has only 4 bits so i was not sure what character it belongs to.

Comment: What is you suggestion for continuing?

Comment: @user3768971 correct your xor? 00111 xor 01010 = 01101

Comment: all characters have 5 bits.

Comment: yeah i saw it, should be correct now: 01101 01100 01100 00010 01011   the corrosponding letters are now "N" "M" "M" "C" and "L"

Comment: so if the assumptions are correct the initial filling was `11010110` Does this check out with the polynomial?

Comment: this is where i get lost.

Comment: @user3768971 First study how an LFSR with given polynomial actually works.

Comment: I get the output `01101 01100 01100 00010 01011 01101 01001 10100 11111 10111` for the first 50 bits, which seems OK. So then you can decrypt..

Comment: If the first 8 bits are just the initial filling in reversed order as it is, it does check out with the polynomial. Our polynomial is of a degree of n= 8 making the taps at 0,1,5,6,8 if im not wrong

Comment: @user3768971 yes, we XOR the bits 0,1,5,6 (0 being the rightmost) and shift that in as the new bit at the top and we output the rightmost bit (the one we just used).

Comment: I seem to not quite get how you calculated the 50 bits, the first 25bits we did using xor "HELLO" xor "KIHJF", but how did you do the last 25?

Comment: @user3768971 As I described. I only used 8 bits plus the taps. The first $17$ confirmed the xor, the next 25 are computed the same way.

Comment: what did you get the plaintext to be? so I know i'm on the right track.

Comment: @user3768971 I haven’t  computed it yet. Why don’t you do it.

Comment: @user3768971 my initial filling yielded valid plain text. After 'HELLO' there is no  space but something else. Go and program it too, it shouldn't be too hard.

Answer (score 0):

Added as an answer due to its importance: **A secret polynomial affords no extra security for LFSRs** (which are weak to begin with) due to the Berlekamp Massey attack which works as soon as $2d$ known plaintext (equivalently ciphertext) bits are available. Here $d$ is the degree of the characteristic polynomial.

Of course, knowing HELLO is more than enough to even break a length 12 primitive LFSR, and keeping the taps secret won't help.